# Win10 Node.js execSync errors

Tags: node.js, windows, imagemagick

I'm trying to create a simple bot that will be able to detect when certain events occur on my PC (I know node.js is not the best solution to do that, but I'm just trying to see what I can do with node.js).

I take a screenshot using `nircmdc.exe` and crop out a specific region. I want to compare that region with ImageMagick and do additional stuff with a node.js script, but I'm stuck at the first part.

My script:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var output = child_process.execSync('compare.exe -metric mse "images/screenGrab.jpg" "images/knownRegion.jpg" null').toString();
console.log(output);
console.log('Done!');
```

If I use the same images, I get no error:

```
D:\app\nodejs>node compareRegion.js
0 (0)
Done!
```

However if I use different images, I still can see the output, but node.js fails out with an error

```
D:\app\nodejs>node compareRegion.js
12660.3 (0.193184)child_process.js:526
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: compare.exe -metric mse "images/screenGrab.jpg" "images/knownRegion.jpg" null
12660.3 (0.193184)
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:483:13)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:523:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\app\nodejs\compareRegion.js:30:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
```

I can see the result `12660.3 (0.193184)`, but the script fails afterwards.

Is there a way I can suppress this error, as the result came through, or do something else?.. Dunno, first time using node.js :)